# Методы в обобщениях

Tags: java, generics

Имеется класс:

```
public class Box<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private T o;

    public Box() {

    }

    public Box(T o) {
        super();
        this.o = o;
    }

    T min(T t1, T t2) {
        T t3 = null;
        int result = t1.compareTo(t2);
        return t3;
    }
}
```

В строке `int result= t1.compareTo(t2);` выбивает ошибку. Что делать, если я хочу сравнить два объекта, внутри которых уже имплементирован интерфейс `Comparable`, но хочу и сохранить данный класс обобщённым.

Comment: Зачем вам нужно имплементировать интерфейс `Comparable`?

Comment: Я имплементирую его в два отдельных класса и хочу, чтобы их можно было добавить в Box и дальше без проблем вызвался метод min().

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы пользоваться интерфейсом `Comparable` в обобщённом классе вам нужно расширить связанный тип этим интерфейсом.

```
class Box<T extends Comparable<T>> {}
```

Comment: Однако в данном случае уже происходит наследование по ArrayList<T>. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: мне не совсем понятно зачем вам нужно наследование по `ArrayList<T>`. Для того чтобы исправить ошибку вам нужно лишь воспользоваться этим ответом.  Если вы добавите наследование, то это не повлияет на решение этой проблемы.

Comment: Я не могу изменять класс, мне нужно изменить именно метод. 
Данный класс наследуется по ArrayList и может добавлять объекты. Мне нужно сравнить два объекта в Box у которые имплементят интерфейс comparable. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как изменить метод T min() чтобы можно было сравнить эти два объекта?

Comment: изменить метод можно так `<U extends Comparable<U>> U min(U u1, U u2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Если класс имплементирует **comparable**, то в нем должен быть 
должен быть определен  метод compareTo() вида

```
@Override
public int compareTo(User user) {
 //
}
```

В вашем случае из-за этого вылетает ошибка.
[Подробнее здесь](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.6.php)

Comment: Где его переопределить? 
И как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Так как это обобщение `<T>`, то он не может сравнить два обьекта пока ты их не инициализируешь одним из типов (byte, double, integer, float, long или short).